# wordpress 404 page not found permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress

i have change my wordpress Permalink Settings Default `http://localhost/mywebsite/?p=123` to   Post name `http://localhost/mywebsite/sample-post/` .

then i create a page. its not working.
404 page not found.

have any solution for this **with out plugin** .

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

**resolved**

This problem in local host. so we nee to  **turn on rewrite module** in Apache.

so If you are using XAMPP or WAMP package then you will find the file at:

> {xampp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
>
> {wamp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf

Search for the following string:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

remove the ‘#’ sign

## restart wamp , xamp

Comment: rewrite_module is turned on but I still can't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings-> Permalink Setting -> Again Select Radio Button and Click Save Button

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there exist an htaccess file in your WordPress home directory as shown above. If it is not there create one:

```
$ sudo nano /var/www/html/.htaccess
```

and copy paste the below to it

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule># END WordPress
```

Press ctrl+x and press y to save the file. And restart apache by

$ sudo service apache2 restart

You would want to tell apache to follow your .htaccess file. You can do this by editing the apache.conf file

```
$sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache.conf
```

Scroll down to the line 
By default it will be:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

change the value of AllowOverride to All so now it becomes:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Press ctrl+x and press y to save the configuration file. In order to make this changes to server first enable the mod_rewrite by.

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And then restart the server

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Done!

Source: https://www.wst.space/riddling-with-wordpress-permalink-setup-issues/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else facing this problem.

Make sure you have the write access while changing permalink settings. Check if you have `.htaccess` file and the following content exist:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpressfoldername/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpressfoldername/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```