# 404 error when creating new site in wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress

it turns out that recently I work in a multisite project in wordpress, which when creating the new sites when trying to enter only appears a 404 screen, but this error has been presented recently, before they worked perfectly and now the existing ones and even the new ones present it and the truth is that I do not know what to do, any idea guys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wordpress 404 page not found permalinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059341/wordpress-404-page-not-found-permalinks)

Answer (score 0):

try updating the permalinks (settings > permalinks) by just save them.